# Как скомпилировать проект Python2.7 в один .exe? pyinstaller не может найти Build.py

Tags: python, python-2.x, компилятор, pyinstaller

Имеется проект из 2х файлов: mainUserForm.py и conf.py.
Рассматривал несколько вариантов: 
zxFreeze - сейчас закомпилировал, но получается целая куча файлов и большого размера. На моем компе работает, а на другом уже нет.
pyinstaller - больше всего меня интересует, но используя  [инструкцию по компилированию](http://lazycleric.blogspot.ru/2012/07/pyinstaller.html) скачал и распаковал pyinstaller, сконфигурировал его изменив `Configure.py` (на всякий случай установил через cmd командой: `pip instal pyinstaller` - и только тогда он появился в списке установленных модулей, проверив через команду: `pip list`) создал свой биновский файл со следующим кодом:

```js
@echo off

set progname=mainUserForm
set pyinstaller_dir=C:\Python27\PyInstaller-3.2

%pyinstaller_dir%\Makespec.py --onefile --icon=icon.ico --name=%progname% main.py -X -c 
%pyinstaller_dir%\Build.py %progname%.spec

rd build /s /q
del warn%progname%.txt
del logdict2.6.6.final.0-1.log
del %progname%.spec
copy dist\%progname%.exe %progname%.exe
rd dist /s /q
echo.
pause
```

не может найти `Build.py`, вот:
[image: результат использования pyinstaller]

Что я не правильно делаю.

Comment: Не знаю жив ли ещё, но раньше был довольно неплохой проект py2exe. Из минусов - не умел собирать сложные библиотеки. Ну и размер программ получался огромным

Comment: cxFreeze на моей памяти довольно сносно работал. Freeze самостоятельно тащит даже DLL из numpy, scipy, отлично собирает графические библиотеки типа TkInter. Единственный минус - большой размер.

Comment: Вы используете инструкцию для версии 1.5.1. В текущей версии нет файлов, упоминаемых в статье, поэтому ничего не работает. Пользуйтесь тем, что в ответе.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Зайдите в папку с файлом, который нужно упаковать в example.exe (cd %path%):

```
pyinstaller --onefile example.py
```

Если и так не помогло, то возможно поможет так:

```
C:\python27\Python27.exe pyinstaller --onefile example.py
```

[**Полная документация по модулю pyinstaller**](https://pythonhosted.org/PyInstaller/usage.html)

Если есть желание добавить иконку, то [скачиваем иконку](http://www.iconsearch.ru/) в формате **icon_name.ICO**

```
pyinstaller --onefile --icon icon_name.ico example.py
```

Начните с малого:

- Вместо двух файлов соберите один, ибо в любом случае при импортировании модуля его код выполняется полностью.
- Соберите сначала с минимальными параметрами, как указано выше
  Потом можно будет и иконку добавить и логи удалить

Comment: А иконку можно менять?

Comment: Не ленитесь читать документацию!!!